# Функция работающая на всех View Controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Как сделать функцию работающую на всех view controller?
у меня получается только на стартовом экране с помощью этого кода:

```
var audioplayer = AVAudioPlayer()

class ViewController: UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

@IBAction func tooglePlay(_ sender: Any) {

        if audioplayer.isPlaying {
            audioplayer.pause()
        } else {
            audioplayer.play()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку эта функция связана с конкретной кнопкой в IB, у вас есть два варианта:

1. Скопировать и вставить эту функцию во все ViewController'ы, которые её используют
2. Если audioplayer обладает глобальной областью видимости, как у вас в примере, то функцию для работы с ним можно вынести в расширение ViewController'а и звать внутри IBAction'а:

---

```
extension UIViewController {
  func toggleAudioPlayer() {
    if audioplayer.isPlaying {
       audioplayer.pause()
    } else {
       audioplayer.play()
    }
  }
}

// В любом ViewController:
@IBAction func togglePlayer(_ sender: Any) {
  toggleAudioPlayer()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите сделать функцию работающую на всех ВьюКонтроллерах, то как вариант можно обратиться к Абстракции.

```
 class MainViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        logTxt()
    }

    func logTxt(){
        print("class MainViewController func logTxt")
    }
}

class ViewController1: MainViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}

class ViewController2: MainViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

В консоле будет следующий лог :

```
class MainViewController func logTxt
```

Т.е. Создать главный ВьюКонтроллер (он же есть "родитель" а именно `MainViewController`) и сделать его родительским классом для ваших `ViewController'ов` (ViewController1, ViewController2 и тд.) и то что вы вызовите в родителе (т.е MainViewController) внутри viewDidLoad() или же можете вызвать внутри любого класса который установил у себя родителя MainViewController(т.е ViewController1 или ViewController2 и тд) внутри viewDidLoad(). Они все будут работать. Так же вы можете пере определить эти методы внутри любого дочернего класса например так:

```
class ViewController1: MainViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func logTxt() {
    print("class ViewController1 func logTxt")
}
```

}

В консоле будет следующий лог :

```
class ViewController1 func logTxt
```

Можете прочить про ООП. Про наследование и Абстрактные классы. 
Удачи вам.